# Call external API using oAuth2

Tags: resttemplate, spring-oauth2

I need to call an external API from my spring boot project.
The external API is using OAuth 2 security authentication using `client_credentials`.
I have the client id and secret key. Can `RestTemplate` be used?
Can you suggest how to pass the id and key as part of the API call? Any example?

Comment: You need to have access_token to make an external API call. To get an access token you need to call access_token endpoint with client id and password. You must have a token endpoint. I don't know about spring boot but this is the concept of oAuthy2.

Comment: I have the access token url, client id and secret. I need to call the api , but how to pass these parameters?

Comment: please check this https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-client-credentials-flow

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestTemplate too but I would suggest that WebClient will be more better as it is reactive and asynchronous and RestTemplate may be depreciated for future use (maybe not too).

Please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2

```html
@Autowired
WebClient client;

public Mono<String> obtainSecuredResource() {
    String encodedClientData = 
      Base64Utils.encodeToString("bael-client-id:bael-secret".getBytes());
    Mono<String> resource = client.post()
      .uri("localhost:8085/oauth/token")
      .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedClientData)
      .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials"))
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
      .flatMap(tokenResponse -> {
          String accessTokenValue = tokenResponse.get("access_token")
            .textValue();
          return client.get()
            .uri("localhost:8084/retrieve-resource")
            .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(accessTokenValue))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
        });
    return resource.map(res ->
      "Retrieved the resource using a manual approach: " + res);
}
```